# Cycles diffuse bake always has seams/light bleed between intersecting/close geometry regardless of texture resolution

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, texture-baking, baking

I really hope to get some help because I'm at my wits end trying to get Cycles bake to work with me here. For context, our team is using a mobile game engine to run a 3D explore-able world. The world is mostly geometric/architectural so nothing crazy. Unfortunately when baking diffuse for lightmaps (in secondary UV using SimpleBake with Denoising) there's always, ALWAYS distracting seams between close geometry
(including instances of light bleed):[image: lightbleed][image: holes near close geometry][image: obvious seam](and many more similar examples)

As much as I wish this were a simple UV bleed problem, there's ample padding between islands and the baking margin is pretty generous (but not enough to bleed into neighboring islands of course). regardles of how I generate the UVs (done this 10s of times at this point) the seams are always in places where geometry get close or intersect. I use Smart UV project as the unwrapping method then use PackMasterPro V2 to pack them as efficiently as possible.

Some troubleshooting:

- Increasing lightmap size (to 4k): Nope.
- spreading across 2 lightmaps, doubling lightmap resolution (2 4k
  maps): Nope.
- Optimizing UVs to use as much texture space as possible: Nope
- Removing all unseen geometry and making sure all surfaces minimize intersection: Nope.
- Supersampling the bake resolution then downsizing resulting maps: Nope.
- Triangulate meshes so tris are consistent: Nope.
- Disabled all displacement modifiers and materials: Nope.

My last reprise at this point is to re-do the mesh so it's watertight and there's no possible place pieces of free geometry can get close or intersect anywhere. This feels like an excessive solution for such a seemingly simple problem. We haven't had a problem close to this when using Unity to bake lighting... am I missing something?

Comment: Hello and welcome, please add some screenshots to show us more about the issue, remember, the more, the better to help you

Comment: Sorry about that, added pictures to help

Comment: I am sorry but can you please tell me the basic outline of your problem, so that we can help?

Comment: @Aster17 
I'm using Cycles bake to bake the lightmaps of an environment, there's 2 4k maps that make up the baked lighting of the scene. Unfortunately there are ugly, distracting black seams and lightbleed in many places, primarily where two pieces of geometry meet/intersect. The troubleshooting steps I took help somewhat but do not solve the issue

Comment: hello, maybe share a file with 2 of these objects so that we can check? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots here's the file, it's, it just contains a couple of the problem structures from the full scene: https://pasteall.org/blend/25da36a21d7d487a9450ca73e22694be

Comment: I can't see the same thing in the file you share, I hope someone will help

Comment: @moonboots Could SimpleBake be to blame?

Comment: @CaseyCo, I don't understand the confusion guys, anyone who is baking will see seams contact shadows when trying to bake two or more objects that are not connected to each other, unfortunately the only way I have found so far is to BOOLEAN the meshes together (or join the vertex) that will remove the contact shadow because it will be one mesh.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bake margin, change the type from *Adjacent faces* to *Extend*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: This explains what to do, but not why it works.